# Adding padding-bottom to a page where all elements are positioned absolutely

Tags: html, css

So i have this HTML page where there are 3 main elements, a side navigation bar, a header, and a data section, which for some reason are all positioned absolutely. Briefly it looks something like this:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
}
header{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 144px;
  top: 0;
}
.data {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 192px);
  top: 168px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="data"><div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Where i need 24px of margin between header and .data and between data and the bottom of the page. It works fine until i insert more content into .data so that it stretches beyond the min-height specified. So i lose the bottom margin of the page. I tried adding content with :after but it didn't work. Any suggestions?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The body has a margin of 8px by default set it to 0 if you want it to look smoothly and then change the min-height to height as a way to stop the element from extending over the set value. However if you add more content that the element can hold within it self the contents will overflow the element so you will have to set the overflow of your element (i would recommend you to use auto so your content would be accessible), adding this to your code should fix your problem

```
 body{
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
 }
.data {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 192px);
  top: 168px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

Comment: No sadly this doesn't help. I'm actually trying to make sure the margin is always there, not get rid of it.

Comment: I obviously didn't understood your question, okay so now i believe that you are supposed to  change **min-height: calc(100vh - 192px);** to **height: calc(100vh - 192px);** as a way to prevent the div from extending over the set value but if you add more content than the element's height the content will overflow the .data element (but the **overflow** property will handle it) @ArashChM

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I had in mind in case nothing worked, but I want to avoid using a scroll bar. I want the .data section to fill the page should the content be less than enough to fill it, but i need .data to expand if there is more content. And as of now everything works as intended except when .data expands further than min-height, it sticks to the bottom of the page and the page looks crappy.

Comment: Okay so as i understand what you need so far is that you need the container to extend when there is more content but you still need the bottom margin to be visible and each time you add more content to your element you are losing your bottom margin even if you use **margin-bottom:24px;** ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I did try margin on .data and padding on body (Although I know it's so stupid of me to try it, because the body height is equal to my browser height no matter what the height of .data is, as it is positioned absolutely and already removed from the normal flow) and none of them work. I think I can find a way around this by manually assigning body height using JavaScript, but I actually prefer to do this in pure CSS.

Comment: The height: 100%; seems to have no effect on the page, removing it only causes the body element's height to collapse to 0, but no visual changes occur.

Comment: seems you are experienced, i believe you will find a way to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Add margin bottom to .data class in css

```
.data {position: absolute;  width: 100%;  min-height: calc(100vh - 192px);  top: 168px; margin:0 0 24px 0;}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I try this the margin is there, but it kind of overflows the page. I can see there is 24px of margin-bottom when I inspect the element, but it has no effect, something like the vertical margin collapse is happening here I guess.

Comment: I saw your piece of code work even though i added more content, and compared it to my code, I realized the problem was the content in .data was also positioned absolutely, so what I did was specify the margin-bottom for the content not the box(the .data div) and this solved my problem.